# ServiceStack: Send JSON string instead DTO via POST

Tags: servicestack

I would like to send a string (JSON formatted) to my webservice instead using a DTO.

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient(absoluteUrl);
client.Post<T>(absoluteUrl, data);
```

But, after to do change my data (DTO object) to a JSON string, I'm getting a ServiceStack Exception: Internal Server Error. Looks like the ServiceStack Post/Send method changes my JSON request.

Is it possible or is there any way to avoid it? Someone else had the same issue?

UPDATE 1: I'm using this approach because of the OAuth authentication. I'm generating a HMAC by request.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HTTP Utils](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Http-Utils) to send raw JSON, e.g:

```
var response = absoluteUrl.PostJsonToUrl(data)
    .FromJson<T>();
```

ServiceStack's [.NET Service Clients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-client) provide Typed API's to send Typed Request DTO's, it's not meant for POST'ing raw strings but I've just added support for sending raw `string`, `byte[]` and `Stream` [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/4953e127245178a20782c4ba1747ce39f8b56a58) so now you can send raw data with:

```
var requestPath = request.ToPostUrl();

string json = request.ToJson();
var response = client.Post<GetCustomerResponse>(requestPath, json);

byte[] bytes = json.ToUtf8Bytes();
response = client.Post<GetCustomerResponse>(requestPath, bytes);

Stream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
response = client.Post<GetCustomerResponse>(requestPath, ms);
```

This change is available from v4.0.43+ that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

#### Sharing Cookies with HttpWebRequest

To have different HttpWebRequests share the same "Session" you just need to share the clients Cookies, e.g. after authenticating with a `JsonServiceClient` you can share the cookies with HTTP Utils by assigning it's `CookieContainer`, e.g:

```
var response = absoluteUrl.PostJsonToUrl(data,
     requestFilter: req => req.CookieContainer = client.CookieContainer)
    .FromJson<T>();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The reason I'm using the JsonServiceClient is because I'm generating a token per each request. I've tried with this approach and I'm getting unauthorized. I'll update my post with this important detail.